# List sub-pages, but skip 1st level

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

How can I list subpages but skip the first level of pages?

Here is my current query, but I want it to drill down 1 level deeper and only list *sub-sub-pages*.

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'page','numberposts' => 10,'post_parent' => $post->ID);
$subpages = get_posts($args);
foreach($subpages as $post) :
setup_postdata($post);
?>
<div>  
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>    
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
array_shift($subpages);
```

Will knock the first item out of the array.